# PHP_VERSION_ID contains old version

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have enabled php 7.3 `sudo a2enmod php7.3` but PHP_VERSION_ID contains old version 50640(apache restarted). Here is what is the server version

```
php -v
PHP 7.3.15-3+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Feb 23 2020 07:23:33) ( NTS )
```

what else need to change?

Comment: The CLI and Apache's versions can be different. Output `phpversion()` on a test page. https://www.php.net/phpversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/php5.6-fpm.conf solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to create a file in your web folder and add

```
<?php

phpinfo()
```

Make sure your apache has been moved to the new PHP version.

Can you share the DISTRO and what steps you take to enable the PHP 7.3

Thank you

Comment: Can you confirm your web will see your version 7.3 adding that file will confirm you are on PHP 7.3 run by the browser? You need to provide more info, you could end up as CLI to be on 7.3 but your apache it's still linked to old version

Comment: Doing `php -v` says its being done from the terminal, you are suggesting using the webserver environment. They can be different

Comment: Yes, but if the apache sees the old PHP he has to do like: Edit your httpd.conf to load the PHP module, locate LoadModule and specify " php5_module modules/libphp(VERSION).so". I'm not 100% I`m nginx(fpm) guy

Comment: @ChristianGabs here is what in apache2.conf <FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

Comment: @OleksandrIY, that will not define what version will use. In general, if you have an old version and new version you need to use (fpm) <FilesMatch \.php$>
      SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
 </FilesMatch>

Comment: @ChristianGabs did that no luck still same version

Comment: Did you install php7.3-fpm ?

Comment: found the reason, I had to remove /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/php5.6-fpm.conf and work well after that

Comment: As I expected, you use fpm for loading PHP. With fpm, you could have multiple PHP versions for a different project on the same machine. You don't need to do that, you have to specify the version on apache config.